# Not allowed to download local resource using form

Tags: javascript, form-submit

I have the following form:

```
<form method="get" action="D:\classes.zip">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <input class="btn btn-profil btn-sm" name="downloadZIP" value="D:\classes.zip" type="submit">
        <span class="btn-download"></span>
</div>
```

I am trying to make the input download the classes.zip when the users clicks on it. But instead I am getting this error:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/classes.zip
```

Comment: try to give full path like : User/Username/D:/classes.zip

Comment: Are you running this under `http://localhost`?  If so you'll have a security issue (due to a cross-domain call from http: to file:).

Comment: @Archer yes I am

Comment: You won't be able to access that file, in that case.  If the file was in the same folder as the html file trying to access it (for example) then you could just use the filename and it would access it over http.

Comment: @Archer thank you for your answer but I can't change the upload folders..

Comment: That was an example - not a solution.  What I'm saying is that you need to replace `d:\classes.zip` with `http://localhost/classes.zip` (or just `classes.zip`), but obviously a path to the file that is correct.  You cannot access `file://` from a page running under `http://`.  Are you going to be putting this on a web server?

Comment: @Archer yes I will be putting my app on a web server.

Comment: So you will be downloading the file from the web server, not from the local file system.  It will need to be accessible by the web server (IIS, Apache etc.) and will have a Url - `http://somedomain.com/folder/classes.zip` (for example).  That will work fine.

Comment: Browsers are sandboxed and don't allow these types of request for security purposes. Local path/directory path is for user using that PC, web server is for outsiders, that is why you can not use local path for outsiders.